# variance of the difference of two independent variables is the sum of variances

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, descriptive-statistics

It is said that variance of the difference of two independent variables is the sum of variances (topic - Confidence intervals. Two means. Independent samples)

I tried to experiment with small dataset of two variables. i found that sum of variance of 2 independent variable is not equal to variance of difference. the experiment is below:-

new york apple price [$3.80, $3.76, $3.87, $3.99, $4.02, $4.25,$4.13, $3.98] its variance = 0.027

LA apple price - [$3.02, $3.22, $3.24, $3.02, $3.06, $3.15, $3.81, $3.44], variance = 0.071

Their difference in prices = [0.78, 0.54, 0.63, 0.97, 0.96, 1.10, 0.32, 0.54] - variance = 0.0715

sum of LA apple price variance and NY apple price variance = 0.098 which not equal to variance of difference = 0.0715

can someone explain me why is it so please?

Comment: The prices are correlated and therefore not independent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the correlation between them is 0.3 which is weak

Comment: Yes you are right I tried to bring down their correlation to near zero..and I noticed that variance are closing matching up

Answer (score 6):

The relevant equation is $V(X-Y) = V(X)+V(Y)-2Cov(X,Y).$
The correlation may seem small to you, but @whuber's Comment
is exactly correct.

Computations in R for your apple prices:

```
ny = c(3.80, 3.76, 3.87, 3.99, 4.02, 4.25, 4.13, 3.98)
la = c(3.02, 3.22, 3.24, 3.02, 3.06, 3.15, 3.81, 3.44)
var(ny)
[1] 0.02711429
var(la)
[1] 0.07177143

cor(ny,la)
[1] 0.310884
cov(ny,la)/(sd(ny)*sd(la))
[1] 0.310884

plot(ny, la, pch=10)
```

[image]

Finally:

```
var(ny-la)
[1] 0.07145714
var(ny)+var(la)-2*cov(ny,la)
[1] 0.07145714
```

Note: One couldn't possibly have just $V(X + Y) = V(X) + V(Y),$ without restriction,
because, if $X \equiv Y,$ then we'd have $V(X + Y) = V(2X) = 4V(x) \ne V(X) + V(X) = 2V(X).$

Comment: Thank you so much now I understood it perfectly. That was perfect explanation!